# Array Push not working inside Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why does a simple array push not working inside an angular controller?

HTML:

```
<div id="MyApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("mainController",function ($scope) {
var array= ["mango"];
   $scope.add= function () {
    console.log("in add");
    array.push["banana"];
    console.log(array);
   };
});
```

This looks to be a plain and simple logic. However I cant make out why it is not updating the array variable. TIA

Comment: `Array.push(item)` is a method so you need `()` not `[]`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
array.push("banana");
```

Currently you're using `array.push` as an object and [accessing its member property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) 'banana' without doing anything. What you have is equivalent to

```
array.push.banana;
```

Comment: Thanks @oldrinb I was sure it was a small mistake but could not able to find it out. Thanks for the pointing it out to me.